# How to create an index.html that can receive and verify video frames with digital signatures using RSA and BLAKE2?

Tags: javascript, flask, client, rsa, digital-signature

I'm working on a project where I need to display a video stream on a webpage, along with digital signatures for each frame. I have a Flask server that sends the video frames and their corresponding digital signatures. However, I'm unsure how to implement the verification process using RSA-PSS and BLAKE2 in the index.html file.

Here's the app.py code, please note that the frame that is returned is in JPEG format:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import requests
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import pss
from Crypto.Hash import BLAKE2s
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response

from camera_opencv import Camera

# s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
# s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
# private_ip = s.getsockname()[0]
# public_ip = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org').text
# s.close()

app = Flask(__name__)

key = RSA.generate(2048)
public_key = key.publickey().export_key()
private_key = key.export_key()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('index.html', public_key=public_key.decode())

def sign_frame(frame):
    blake2_hash = BLAKE2s.new()
    blake2_hash.update(frame)
    signature = pss.new(key).sign(blake2_hash)
    
    return frame, signature

def gen(camera):
    """Video streaming generator function."""
    yield b'--frame\r\n'
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        frame, signature = sign_frame(frame)

        yield b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + signature + b'\r\n--frame\r\n'

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    """Video streaming route."""
    return Response(gen(Camera()), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True)

# print(f"Private IP: {private_ip}")
# print(f"Public IP: {public_ip}")
```

Here are the requirements I need to meet:

1. Receive the video frame and digital signature from the server.
2. Verify the frame using RSA-PSS and BLAKE2.
3. Display the video if the verification is successful, and show an error message if the verification fails.

I would appreciate any guidance or example code on how to accomplish this using JavaScript or any related technologies. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Video decoding is usually performs by a hardware element in CPU or GPU, I don't think that you can access the decoded frames on client side on JavaScript level to implement your frame verification system.